# How to backup SQL Server 2012 database to flat file and again restore the flat file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to backup SQL Server 2012 database to flat file and again restore the flat file to bring up the database?

Comment: You haven't even tried to Google this, have you??

Comment: It's called a **database backup** and it produces a `.bak` file which you can restore later on

Comment: Creating flat files is usually done with external tools - most SQL clients have some feature to do a bulk "unloading"

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to create a flat (text) file instead of a true database backup, you can do it via scripting.  In this case, you'd want to script both schema and data, or simply the data if you have no need for a schema script.

Through the UI, this is done via the database scripting interface (right-click the database -> tasks -> generate script).  Select the objects you're interested in (or the entire database), then on the 'set scripting options' form, click the 'Advanced' button.  Scroll down until "Types of data to script" is visible, then pick either "Schema and data" or "Data Only":
[image]

The output will be a SQL script.  If you examine the script, you'll see that after the schema definition statements (if you chose to generate these) are INSERT statements to re-create the data.

Be aware, however, that this method is by no means optimal.  Records with unusual contents (e.g. characters that will break the insert statement) will not be handled well when you try to rebuild the data.

(Commenters... be aware I am addressing the question itself, not the "why?" which the question begs.)

**EDIT**:  If you want to do this though a maintenance plan, you'll need to use a third-party tool to generate the INSERT statements.  There are several:  [SQLPubWiz](https://sqlhost.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DPW%20Command%20Line%20Interface) is one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your experience with SQL Server, so what I normally do is:

1. go to my DB -> Tasks -> Generate script -> and script the entire database.
   This is to save the structure of the db, so you can build it on a new pc.
2. go again to the DB -> Tasks -> Export Data -> and here I choose as destination Access instead of Flat File, since I have bad experiences with Flat Files.

Once the export is done, I import it the same way as above into my new db on the new pc.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I want to create a maintenance plan to schedule backup of database to a flat file not ".bak" file.